# find the curvature and torsion of a curve without reparametrization by arclength

Tags: differential-geometry

I know there are formulas for the curvature and torsion for curves that are parametrized by arclength, but what if the curve is not parametrized by arclength how can we find its curvature and its torsion without reparametrizing it. There are 3 cases: the curvature of a curve in 2 dimensions, the curvature of a curve in 3 dimensions , and the torsion of a curve in 3 dimensions. How can i start doing this ?

Comment: There are formulas for these in terms of a general parameter see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet–Serret_formulas

Comment: Best thing to do is to use the chain rule that adjusts for non-arclength parametrization. To see examples of this, you might look at (among other places) [my differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).